# Can this statement be shortened using a lambda function?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following script:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class IdleBehavior : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    public override void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Counter", Increment(animator.GetFloat("Counter")));
    }

    private float Increment(float time)
    {
        return time += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

...and was just wondering if the following line could be shortened using a lambda expression?

```c#
animator.SetFloat("Counter", Increment(animator.GetFloat("Counter")));
```

I tried myself, but just got a bunch of errors.

Comment: You could just write `animator.SetFloat("Counter", animator.GetFloat("Counter") + Time.deltaTime));` if you want to save the other function. I don't think you can do much more since you will need to call `SetFloat` anyways. Edit: See answer of Galandil, you could save that as member somewhere (basically a delegate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a lambda expression, you just execute the addition in the parameter itself:

```cs
animator.SetFloat("Counter", animator.GetFloat("Counter") + Time.deltaTime);
```

However, if you want to use a lambda expression with which to add a value to an animator parameter, you can do it as follows:

```cs
Action<string,float> addFloatToAnimatorParameter =
    (str, value) => animator.SetFloat(str, animator.GetFloat(str) + value));
addFloatToAnimatorParameter("ParameterName", Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completness: It's `System.Action` or `UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction`.

Comment: `System`, but it can work with `UnityAction` too. I prefer personally to use always `System`'s `Func` and `Action` unless a `UnityAction` is really needed: so far, IIRC they're needed when using `AddListener` (it doesn't accept a `System.Action`) and/or if you want to serialize the delegate in the Inspector.

Comment: You're right. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks. One other question, since I'm constantly calling animator.SetFloat and animator.GetFloat in the update function, is there any way to cache those into variables so it's more performance friendly?

Comment: You can't. But you can do something to speed up the performance of the various `Animator.Set` methods: don't use the `string` argument overload, use the `int` ID overload. In `Start`, get the ID by using `int parameterID = animator.StringToHash("ParameterName");`, and afterwards use that ID when changing the value of parameters, i.e.: `animator.SetFloat(parameterID, value);`

Comment: Can't edit previous comment: it should be `Animator.StringToHash` and not `animator.StringToHash`